# Chrome autofill feature not working in custom form

Tags: google-chrome, autofill, browser-automation

I tried to create a form using the instructions given in 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill. 
But it seems like chrome auto-fill feature is not working. It is not saving the form data from the custom form. The auto-fill seems to be working only with the data which I directly enter to the auto-fill setting of the browser.

I'm not quite sure why it is not saving the data when I submit the form. Am I missing something here? Please help**!!**

The Chrome Version I'm using is **55.0.2883.87** (64-bit) and my OS is **Fedora 24**.